# fusionreactor installation error Backing store not available

Tags: coldfusion, install4j, coldfusion-10, backing, fusionreactor

I am trying to install **FusionReactor_windows_4_5_5** on my ColdFusion 10 / Windows 7 (32bit) system. But it is giving me an error:

```
Setup detected a problem

Please ensure that the Java System Preferences Backing Store has appropriate permission!
Additional information can be found in the following documents:

http://www.fusion-reactor.com/support/kb/FRS-198.cfm
http://www.fusion-reactor.com/fr/helpdocs/installation_guide.pdf

The error reported is:
Flush(): Backing store not available.
```

How do I solve it and install FusionReactor successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the FusionReactor support pages found here: [FusionReactor Technote - FRS-198](http://www.fusion-reactor.com/support/kb/FRS-198.cfm) (this was also mentioned in the error that you received)

> *HOW TO FIX IT*
>
> **Insufficient privileges**
>
> The runtime user of the server on which FusionReactor is installed requires read/write access to the Java System Preferences Backing Store. Depending on the operating system, the location of this data store is different.
>
> On Windows the data is stored in the registry hive `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Prefs`, the data belonging to FusionReactor is in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Prefs\com\intergral\fusionreactor`. 
>   Page 14 of the FusionReactor Installation Guide provides you with instructions how to adjust the permissions of this store.
>
> On Linux and Solaris the data is typically stored in the directory `/etc/.java/.systemPrefs` as a hierarchy of directories containing XML files. The data belonging to FusionReactor is in the directory `/etc/.java/.systemPrefs/com/intergral/fusionreactor`. To set the necessary permissions execute the following command as user root:
>
> `chmod -R 777 /etc/.java/.systemPrefs`
>
> **Alternative locations of the System Preferences Backing Store**
>
> - Some JVMs try to create the System Preferences Backing Store in the directory `$JAVA_HOME/.systemPrefs` as a fallback solution if the directory `/etc/.java/.systemPrefs` cannot be created where `$JAVA_HOME` denotes the directory where the JVM itself is located (e.g. /opt/coldfusionmx/runtime/jre ).
> - We strongly recommend you to use `/etc/.java/.systemPrefs` as the one and only location of the System Preferences Backing Store. In case there is already data from other applications in `$JAVA_HOME/.systemPrefs` you should move it to `/etc/.java/.systemPrefs` and delete `$JAVA_HOME/.systemPrefs` afterwards (after you have adjusted the permissions of `/etc/.java/.systemPrefs` properly).
>
> **Clear the System Preferences Backing Store**
>
> - If you attempt to install a license and you get the error message mentioned before:
>
> `Can not upload license: null`
>
> or simply
>
> `null`
>
> then you should stop the application server, clear the content of the Java System Preferences Backingstore and restart the application server.
>
> On a **Windows** machine run the registry editor (regedit.exe or regedt32.exe) and then delete the key
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Prefs\com\intergral\fusionreactor`
>
> On a **UNIX** machine as user root delete the directory
>
> `/etc/.java/.systemPrefs/com/intergral/fusionreactor`
>
> If the permissions are configured correctly uploading a license and activating it will work properly afterwards.
>
> On **MacOS** the System Preferences are stored as a set of *.plist files under the `/Library/Preferences` folder. Once the application server has stopped delete the file `/Library/Preferences/com.intergral.fusionreactor.plist` to clear all Preferences belonging to FusionReactor.